# Docker error :System Error : no space left on device

Tags: docker

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to build my image. Searched on internet and got some links but none of them solved my problem.

Error:
System error: write /cgroup/docker/5dba72d862bf8171d36aa022d1929455af6589af9fb7ba6220b01842c7a7dee6/cgroup.procs: no space left on device.

This is the output of 'df -h':

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda2        56G   24G   29G  46% /
    none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
    tmpfs           385M  1.3M  384M   1% /run
    none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
    none            1.9G  324M  1.6G  17% /run/shm
    none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
    /dev/sda8       761M  3.4M  758M   1% /boot/efi
    /dev/sda3        55G   49G  3.8G  93% /home
    /dev/sda4       275G   48G  213G  19% /opt/drive2
    /dev/sda5       184G   74G  102G  43% /opt/drive3
    /dev/sda6       215G  157G   48G  77% /opt/drive4
    /dev/sda7       129G   23G   99G  19% /opt/drive1
```

Comment: `no space left on device` seems pretty clear: you have no space left on the drive your building your image.

Comment: post a `df -h` so that we check

Answer (score 0):

You have no space in your host machine, where you are trying to build the image. First of all, you have to free some space. If you are using Debian based system this will help you:

- `df -h` (show free space)
- `apt-get autoclean`
- `apt-get autoremove`
- BleachBit (CCleaner-like for Linux).

Moreover, you can optimize your image building following [these Dockerfile tips.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Comment: Still the same issue . I have given the output of 'df -h' for free space

Comment: Can you pull the base image of yours?

Comment: Yes it downloads the base image of Ubuntu for my application

Answer (score 0):

This is common problem if you are using `docker-machine`. In VM is disk smaller. Try cleanup your docker using these commands:

```
# Delete all containers
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
# Delete all images
docker rmi $(docker images -q -f dangling=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason may **docker devicemapper Base Device Size**.
please consider [this](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2016/03/daemon_option_basedevicesize/) or [my answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51799695/3214950)