# Docker Error creating metadata file: no space left on device

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I have the following disk space utilization:

```
Filesystem                                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                                                  32G  2.7M   32G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                 1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /union
tmpfs                                                 1.0G  5.7M 1019M   1% /union/rw
/dev/ram0                                             227M  227M     0 100% /union/image
unionfs                                               1.0G  5.7M 1019M   1% /
devtmpfs                                               32G     0   32G   0% /dev
/dev/mapper/vgroot-var                                 12G   11G  1.4G  89% /union/var
/dev/mapper/vgroot-local                              708G  457G  252G  65% /SYS/localstorage
/dev/mapper/vgroot-scratch                            165G  1.3G  164G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                                                  32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                  32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
192.168.52.254:/srv/ql-common                          14G  4.9G  8.2G  38% /etc/qlustar/common
192.168.52.254:/srv/apps/chroots/focal-base-gpu-gsc3   79G   47G   29G  63% /union/nfs
tmpfs                                                 6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

My problem is: sometimes, when I want to run a new docker image, I receive the following error:

```
Docker Error creating metadata file: no space left on device
```

The only way that I could solve the error is by doing the following procedure:

```
1- Stop docker service
2- empty /var/lib/docker directory
3- reboot machine
```

However, the same error would come back later. I tried all the other solutions such as docker prune, docker rm, docker stop, docker rmi that are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030433/docker-error-system-error-no-space-left-on-device) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device) but the abovementioned error keeps showing.

Is there any way to redirect /var/lib/docker to use another directory with more free space? or is there any other workaround to this problem?

Comment: Normally you should stop docker, mount `/var/lib/docker` from a dedicated partition and then start it again. Are you able to do this?

Comment: Also check if you can reduce docker context size by adding some irrelevant large files/directory in `.dockerignore`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/ /SYS/localstorage/docker/
sudo ln -s /SYS/localstorage/docker/ /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Answer (score 1):

One work around can be check disk utilisation by docker images by running `docker images`.

Identify unwanted images and perform cleanup - this way you can reclaim certain disk space.

If you need more space then you can add separate disk or partition existing disk and then mount it to `/var/lib/docker`

**Note: What ever changes that are being suggested for extending disk partition for `/var/lib/docker` are purely experimental, make sure that you are not performing these steps directly on production environment - You can take this to production only when you had done all necessary testing and confident enough to go ahead with production environment.**

If you are planning to mount `/var/lib/docker` on separate disk or partition then you need to perform below steps:

1. Stop docker containers and stop docker daemon.
2. Take backup of `/var/lib/docker` along with file permission preserved and store it in different location wherever you have enough space (for example /opt/)
3. Remove files at /var/lib/docker
4. Mount your new disk partition to `/var/lib/docker`
5. Restore the backup that you have taken at step #2 and restore it on /var/lib/docker
6. Start your docker daemon and start your containers.

Now, `/var/lib/docker` is mounted on separate disk